# How do I make my site changes seen after I update the site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm fairly new to website making. So the problem is that I didn't like the appearance of my site and made some changes to my website. But I didn't see the changes after I updated my website. Later I found that I had to clear the cache of my chrome browser and then it showed the changes. But the problem is that my visitors aren't gonna do that for me. Like I can't ask the visitors to clear the browser cache just to view my updated website. So how do I make my site update automatically and not having to clear the cache to show the changes that I make in the website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to maintain a version of the released `js` & `css` files

Like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js?v=123456789"></script>
```

So browser wont reload the old js file

Otherwise you can also update the main html filw and include the following in meta tag

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="EXPIRES" CONTENT="somedate">
```

Comment: Do I have to change the name of my css file too to do that?
like for example, if it is
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js?v=123456789"></script>
then should I change my css file name to main.js?v=123456789??

Answer (score 0):

Add `?v=%v%` in `src`, href for `<link>`(css) and `<script>`. And change `%v%` on each changing file.

Comment: I just updated my css file.. How do I add that line? can you show an example